GE gas dryer GFDN110GL0WW service
My GE gas dryer (GFDN110GL0WW)  doesn't start. It has power, and I can navigate and select cycles and I can press the start button, but the drum doesn't turn. I get a different indicator sound when I open the door and press the start button than when I hold the door sensor down and press start meaning the door sensor switch works. I cleaned the lint from the lint trap through the dryer and then to the exhaust line. My three questions:
How do I enter the service mode for this model? Holding start and turning either direction 7 clicks does not work. This model doesn't have a delay start button unless it's extremely well hidden. The schematic has text referencing the service mode, but no instructions for accessing it.
Does this model have a pilot light and if so, where is it so I can check that?
Are there fuses on this model that I can check? I don't see any on the 3 top circuit boards

It says "gas" on the sticker...

Did you try hitting Google with the model number to see if you can download a service manual for that model? It sounds like the techniques you're trying are for another model.

@gnicko Go easy - I added the picture after Trav's comment. The techniques listed were for other GE dryers - I haven't found the service manual, only owner's, installation and schematic for this dryer in which I haven't found instructions for service mode.

once you push start the door should lock, if not replace the door latch

@Traveler Does this dryer even have a door lock?

@Traveler I can't tell whether you're trolling or not. You've asserted that a) the dryer isn't gas and that b) that the problem is a faulty door lock and c) that there's no service mode. I've proven it's gas and I can't find a door lock for sale for this model. While I appreciate that you're ostensibly trying to help, I'm not going to put another picture up showing the schematic's reference to the service mode. What are you getting out of this?

Does this model have a pilot light - I don't know if dryers ever had pilot lights, but considering that furnaces and ovens/cooktops haven't had pilot lights for decades, I'm pretty sure it doesn't - pilot lights are a tremendous waste of gas with the exception of tank water heaters (which need to cycle periodically to keep water hot even if none is used, so pilot light is OK).

Are there fuses on this model that I can check? There are likely multiple fuses - typically both electrical and thermal. If you haven't already, assuming there is an "air only, no heat" option, try running that mode. If that doesn't work then that pretty much rules out any gas-related issues.

It's all good. Maybe this: https://www.allrepairmanuals.com/ge-dryer.htm?model_number=GFDN110GL0WW ?
